# Link WPF Combobox with Postgres Database values

Tags: c#, wpf, postgresql, combobox

I am trying to populate a combobox with data from a postgres database but I cant get it work.

C# code :

```
private void fill_combo()
{
    string CommandText = "select ida from antenne";
    using (NpgsqlConnection sqlConn = new NpgsqlConnection("server=localhost;port=5432;user=postgres;pwd=password;database=BDTelecom"))
    {
        sqlConn.Open();
        NpgsqlCommand sqlCmd = new NpgsqlCommand(CommandText, sqlConn);
        NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        comboBox.Text = "ida";
    }
}
```

XAML code :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the name of the column in the data table that you want to view in the combobox?

Comment: i want to display `ida`

Comment: Why do you need the database data if you just want to display `ida`?

Comment: My table is entitled Antenna, it contains 2 columns `ida` and `radius`.
I want to put the ida in the combobox to make some sql queries and calculations..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the name of the field in the data table (the name of column in the database) is `"ida"` and is of type `string`, that you need to do something like this:

```
comboBox.ItemsSource =
    dt.Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(x => x.Field<string>("ida"));
```

Comment: 'DataTable' ne contient pas de définition pour 'ItemsSource' et aucune méthode d'extension 'ItemsSource'. :(

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say `comboBox.ItemsSource`. See the updated code.

Answer (score 2):

You're retrieving the data, but you're not assigning it to the `ComboBox`.

Assign `dt` as the source, and set the column name you want the user to see.

```
...
da.Fill(dt);
comboBox.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
comboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "ida";
```

Comment: `dt` in `comboBox.ItemsSource = dt;` is underlined, "Impossible de convertir implicitement le type 'System.Data.DataTable' en 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'."